# Need help converting Access query to T-SQL

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2012, case

I have a created field in Access that I am trying to replicate in SQL, but I can't seem to get the CASE statement correct.  Here is the Access query:

```
Missed Deliveries: Sum(IIf([Shipping Notif Calc]="11/30/1999",IIf([PO Delivery Date Calc]-[Confirmation Date Calc]<-5 Or [PO Delivery Date Calc]-[Confirmation Date Calc]>5,1,0),IIf([Confirmation Date Calc]="11/30/1999",IIf([PO Delivery Date Calc]-[Shipping Notif Calc]<-5 Or [PO Delivery Date Calc]-[Shipping Notif Calc]>5,1,0),IIf([Confirmation Date Calc]-[Shipping Notif Calc]<-5 Or [Confirmation Date Calc]-[Shipping Notif Calc]>5,1,0)))))
```

Comment: Please provide any errors or specific difficulties. I can't see why this expression wouldn't work in T-SQL, you can just use `IIf` there (since SQL server 2012, which is the one you've tagged).

Comment: Operand data type date is invalid for subtract operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DATEDIFF function instead of subtracting date columns.

E.g. replace:

```
[PO Delivery Date Calc]-[Confirmation Date Calc]
```

with:

```
DATEDIFF(day, [Confirmation Date Calc], [PO Delivery Date Calc])
```

(Note that you have to swap the order of the dates.)